# ZeroMQ with msgpack, in C++, throws an invalid argument error

Tags: c++, zeromq, msgpack

I am using zeromq to read data from an application which uses msgpack for serializing. The code compiles well but throws an invalid argument error when run. Where am I being wrong.

Here is the error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'zmq::error_t'

what():  Invalid argument
Abort (core dumped)

Here's the code.

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <msgpack.hpp>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
zmq::context_t context (1);

// Open a req port to talk to application
std::string addr = "tcp://127.0.0.1";
std::string req_port = "55555";
zmq::socket_t req (context, ZMQ_REQ);
req.connect(addr+req_port);

// Ask for the subport
zmq::message_t subPortRequest (8);
memcpy (subPortRequest.data(), "SUB_PORT", 8);
req.send(subPortRequest);

zmq::message_t reply;
req.recv(&reply);

std::string sub_port = std::string(static_cast<char*>(reply.data()), reply.size());
std::cout << sub_port << std::endl;


//  Open a sub port to listen to application
zmq::socket_t sub (context, ZMQ_SUB);
std::cout << addr+sub_port << std::endl;
sub.connect(addr+sub_port);

// subscriptions to everything
sub.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", strlen(""));

while(1){
    zmq::message_t reply_topic;
    sub.recv(&reply_topic);
    std::string topic = std::string(static_cast<char*>(reply_topic.data()), reply_topic.size());

    zmq::message_t reply_msg;
    sub.recv(&reply_msg);
    std::string msg = std::string(static_cast<char*>(reply_msg.data()), reply_msg.size());

    msgpack::object_handle oh = msgpack::unpack(msg.data(), msg.size());
    msgpack::object obj = oh.get();
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

} 

}
```

Comment: Where does it crash? Use a debugger to find out. Then look at the function parameters and the manual, what could be wrong ... This way, there are too many unknowns to really help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Most probably the `string` fails to meet the spec:

While the source instructs to do this:

```
zmq::socket_t req ( context, ZMQ_REQ );  // __________.SET [REQ] access point
// Open a req port to talk to application ____________.SET strings
std::string addr     = "tcp://127.0.0.1"; // _________.SET    "IP"-part
std::string req_port = "55555";           // _________.SET "PORT#"-part

req.connect( addr + req_port );           // _________.CONNECT( "IP"+"PORT#" )
```

the ZeroMQ **`.connect()`** method ought get a string of about this shape:

> **`.connect( "tcp://127.0.0.1:55555" );`**
> ------------------------------------------------^

---

> Anyway, **enjoy building the Smart Distributed Systems** with the powers of ZeroMQ

Comment: Sorry I didn't update the post. I figured out soon after posting that the missing colon was indeed the problem. Thanks for helping